# What is the name of this specific pair of angles on the intersection of two lines and a transversa?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is the name of a pair of angles on the intersection of two lines and a transversal where the angles are on oposite sides of the transversal and only one of the angles is between the two lines? I don't know what it would be called. I got this question from a Math is Fun quiz, but the answer I can't find: [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHC4j.png).

Answer (score 1):

Angle $b$ and angle $e$ are consecutive interior angles as $b=c$ because they are vertical angles.